# How to find value of one column in another and change color?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm new to Excel Macro VBA, so please bear with me.

I have an Excel file set up like this:

```
Col1    Col2
----    ----
a       a
b       c
c       e
d       g
e       i
f
g
h
i
j
```

I want to write a VBA macro function that will find values present in `Col2`, in `Col1`, and if it is found, then it will set the font color of that cell to red, in `Col1` ..

So for the example data above, values `a`, `c`, `e`, `g`, `i` in `Col1` should turn to `red` color.

For the above example, let's say that `Col1` values are from `A3:A13`, and `Col2` is from `B3:B13` ..

I'm using Excel 2010 ..

How can I accomplish this in Excel VBA Macro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make it pink .. Cell A1:A10 .. Cell B1:B5 ..

```
Sub Test()
Dim x1, x2 As Integer

For x2 = 1 To 5
  For x1 = 1 To 10
    If Range("A" & Format(x1)).Value = Range("B" & Format(x2)).Value Then          
       Range("A" & Format(x1)).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
  Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Its changing the background color to purple .. I actually want the font color to change to red ..

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to test my skills a little with this, even though @matzone gave exact answer already. I made this Sub which does exactly the same, but using `Range` objects and `.Find()` method. With comments...

```
Private Sub Test()
    FindAndColorMatchesOfTwoColumns "A", "B"
End Sub

Private Sub FindAndColorMatchesOfTwoColumns(colTarget As String, colList As String)
    Dim rLookUp As Range        ' Column range for list compared against
    Dim rSearchList As Range    ' Column range for compare items
    Dim rMatch As Range
    Dim sAddress As String

    ' Set compared against list from colTarget column
    Set rLookUp = Range(colTarget & "1:" & _
                  colTarget & Range(colTarget & "1").End(xlDown).Row)

    ' Loop trough list from colList column
    For Each rSearchList In Range(colList & "1:" & colList & Range(colList & "1").End(xlDown).Row)

        ' Find for a match
        Set rMatch = rLookUp.Find(rSearchList.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rMatch Is Nothing Then
            ' Store first address found
            sAddress = rMatch.Address

            ' Loop trough all matches using .FindNext,
            '   exit if found nothing or address is first found
            Do
                ' Set the color
                rMatch.Font.Color = vbRed

                Set rMatch = rLookUp.FindNext(rMatch)

            Loop While Not rMatch Is Nothing And rMatch.Address <> sAddress
        End If
    Next

    Set rMatch = Nothing
    Set rSearchList = Nothing
    Set rLookUp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The idea is to be more dynamic, accept the two columns as arguments, set search ranges until `Range.End(xlDown).Row` and not fixed counts. Also loop trough only matches.

For original question the simple `.Cells()` nested loops is way simpler, but using `.Find()` would prove alot faster if column counts would go up to thousand(s).

Tested the "long list" hypothesis with this test sub:

```
Private Sub RunTest()
    Dim tStart As Date
    Dim tEnd As Date

    tStart = Timer
    FindAndColorMatchesOfTwoColumns "A", "B"
    tEnd = Timer

    Debug.Print Format(tEnd - tStart, "0.000")


    tStart = Timer
    Test
    tEnd = Timer

    Debug.Print Format(tEnd - tStart, "0.000")
End Sub
```

Added 1500 rows to column A and 184 rows to column B and got **Immediate** view result as:

```
0,266
12,719
```

So there indeed is a huge difference in performance... If OP was only providing simplistic example for question and intends to utilize this in larger sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple few lines of macro would resolve the problem as under:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For j = 1 To Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 1 To Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
       If Cells(j, 2) = Cells(i, 1) Then
         Cells(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
       End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option. It might not be pretty but just goes to show how many different ways there are of achieving the same solution.

```
Sub updateFontColour()

Dim rngCol1 As Range
Dim rngCol2 As Range
Dim myvalue As Long
Dim c As Range

'Set the ranges of columns 1 and 2. These are dynamic but could be hard coded
Set rngCol1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set rngCol2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

'Loop through range 1 (column A) and use the 'Match' function to find a match in range 2 (column B)
For Each c In rngCol1
    On Error Resume Next
    'I use the error handler as the match function returns a relative position and not an absolute one.
    If IsError(myvalue = WorksheetFunction.Match(c.Value, rngCol2, 0)) Then
        'Do noting, just move next
    Else
        c.Font.Color = vbRed
    End If

Next

End Sub
```